# Formulário via GET

Tags: php, html

estou a enviar dados via get pela url o formulario esta desta maneira

```html
<form  action="dashboard.php?link=products/home&so=app_windows" method="GET">
</form>
```

ao enviar redireciona sempre para

```
dashboard/dashboard.php?so=app_android
```

ao invés de ir para

```
dashboard/dashboard.php?link=products/home&so=app_android
```

alguma solução

Comment: Use o `method='post'` que esse problema não irá acontecer.

Comment: sim eu ja usei pelo post mais e que quero pela url pois pelo post essa informção se perde ao troca de pagina já pela url não

Comment: Coloca o formulário completo pra que possamos detectar o que está ocorrendo. Só com o que você postou não dá pra saber o que ocorre.

Answer (score 1):

Você não colocou no código mas quando você usa o método get os valores dos elementos do seu formulário serão inseridos na url. Então provavelmente você tem algo assim:

```
<form  action="dashboard.php?link=products/home&so=app_windows" method="GET">

    <input type="text" name="so" value="app_windows">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

Quando clicar em enviar, essa url será alterada.

Se você usar assim:

```
<form  action="dashboard.php?link=products/home&so=app_windows" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="so" value="app_windows">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

Sua url não irá alterar e você conseguirá pegar os valores via GET da mesma forma.

Ou então você pode fazer isso:

```
<form  action="dashboard.php" method="get">

    <input type="" name="so" value="app_windows">
    <input type="" name="link" value="products/home">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

Depende do que você acha melhor.

Comment: fiz como voce falo criando um <input type="" name="link" value="products/home"> mais agora ele redireciona mais para url dashboard.php?link=products%2Fhome%26&so=app_windows como retiro esses caracteres deixando so a barra dashboard.php?link=products/home&so=app_windows

Comment: @diogoDsa isso não é problema. Dá um `echo $_GET['link']` e veja o resultado. Ele irá ser decodificado.

Comment: E tire o **&** do  `value="products/home&"` não é necessário.